# Showing the filter results in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building an userform that shows a listbox of several items, and the user can select one item of the listbox. Upon selection, I want to filter one worksheet based on the item selected and show the data to the user.
I don't want to show the filtered worksheet, but an image or perhaps a table only with the filtered data.
I manage to build the code to filter and select the range, but I'm having trouble dealing with the data. For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Worksheets("Resumo").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$W$400").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ListBox1.value

    Range("F1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select


End Sub
```

After the selection, I want to show this selection in the userform, as an image or some table that you can't edit.

Can someone suggest me ways to show the data?

Edit1: Thanks for the suggestions, I will show the way I'm currently showing the data to exemplify what I'm trying to do: 
I'm using a message box to show the data (building an array with the data separated by vbCrLf). The problem with msgbox is that I can't position the data correctly, for example:

[image]

How could I keep the message box style and show the data correctly?

Edit2: [Userform listbox to show values from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157813/userform-listbox-to-show-values-from-a-range?rq=1) shows something similar to what I want, but in my case, it is better to work with filters than named ranges because there are several different items to filter for.

Comment: I'd suggest you record a macro starting off right where your current macro ends, where you create a new worksheet, copy and paste your selected data to it, then lock the sheet with a password so that your users can't edit it.

Comment: Can you please explain "having trouble"?

Comment: Also, further to @dwirony's comment, see: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added an example to make our discussion easier

Comment: A messagebox will get really tricky really fast. What if one number is 3 characters, but another is 10?  Perhaps you could output the data you want on a new sheet, and hide rows/columns that you don't need? It will be much easier to maintain I believe than a messagebox which isn't really the best.  Or, actually, a userform might be preferable too.

Comment: @DanielGutierres There's no real solid way to display data in a tabular format on a `MsgBox` (it wasn't really designed for that), however there is a solution that someone else devised [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3839-excel-message-box-to-display-range.html)

Comment: Exactly! I have noticed that problem, but I'm lacking the ability to put that data of variable size in an userform, table, etc

Comment: Any reason you can't use a Table Slicer to do the filtering, and just show the user the filtered table that results (or serve up a copy of that filtered table directly in the grid)?

Comment: I think that will be the solution, probably. Anyway, I made this question to check if there is another option that looks with what I wanted.